# QGIS and PostgreSQL viewing geom columns differently

Tags: qgis, postgresql, geohash

I have a data set of 2 million points, my goal is to cluster the data using geohash codes. I have the geohash code at varying precisions for each point in their own columns.

I created a table for each geohash precision level and populated it with the data from the source dataset. I then turned the geohash code into a point. 
This was done for 3 character geohash precision using the following SQL:

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS tbl_geohash3;

CREATE TABLE tbl_geohash3 AS
SELECT geohash3, COUNT(*) FROM location_tbl
GROUP BY geohash3;

ALTER TABLE tbl_geohash3
ADD COLUMN geom geometry(point, 4326);

UPDATE tbl_geohash3
SET geom = ST_SetSRID(ST_AsText(ST_PointFromGeoHash(geohash3, 3)),4326);
```

In the geometry viewer in Postgres everything looks fine. However when I load it into QGIS its as if its in the wrong projection. I checked the SRID of the newly created table and the source table and they're both correct. I also loaded the location table into QGIS to see if it was the source table but it was perfectly fine.

I dont know where I went wrong with this, can anyone help?

EDIT: I just loaded this layer into geoserver and then onto a webmap with openlayers and it worked totally fine. I'd say this is a QGIS problem.